# No test found with test runner JUnit5

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I'm creating some Unit Test for my app..

I created a several method without any issues.

But now, I created a new one but is not being "read" by JUnit5 as I get the error in the title.

The test is pretty simple

```
@Test
    @DisplayName("ConsultNumber")
    static void consultNumber() throws IOException, SOAPException {
        Response response = new PersonService().getData(login.getToken(), login.getSign(), p.getProperty("cuit"), "999999999");
        assertEquals(response.isSuccess(), true);
    }
```

This are my related imports:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.company.app</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.14.8</lombok.version>
        <log4jdbc.log4j2.version>1.16</log4jdbc.log4j2.version>
        <rest.assured.version>2.3.3</rest.assured.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1</artifactId>
            <version>${log4jdbc.log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest.assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.xml.rpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.47</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.47</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.xml.rpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-loaded.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I just copy and pasted from other test that I have but I don't know why this is not working...

Also I checked and as Run Configuration the selected Test Runner is JUnit5

I also try to create a new test class and add that test in the new class without success. And when I execute all the test, all the test are run except for this one that is not in the summary list.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but the `static` on the method seems suspicious.

Comment: ohh you were right! Please add you comment as answer so I can mark as correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test case is not getting picked up because it is static. Test annotation does not allow static and private method. See the excerpt from the documentation:

> @Test is used to signal that the annotated method is a test method.
>   @Test methods must not be private or static and must not return a value.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Test.html